# Getting the *in* from clojure apps called with clojure apps

Tags: clojure, inputstream, leiningen

So in a clojure project (launched with lein run) I call:

```
(ProcessBuilder. (into-array ["bash" "-c" "cd some-folder ; lein run"])
```

Within the some-folder's project there is loop with (read/line) in it that waits for input from the parent.

However, sending input to:

```
^InputStream (.getOutputStream child-process) ; doesn't work.
```

doesn't reach the clojure code, that is due to lein in turn starting a process. How can I get the stream that the clojure code in the child process is listening to?

Answer (score 0):

My first though is "Why?".  But, if you must, perhaps a [Unix named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) would be a good answer.  This creates a FIFO buffer that both the reader and writer treat like a plain file:

---

### In Unix

Instead of a conventional, unnamed, shell pipeline, a named pipeline makes use of the filesystem. It is explicitly created using `mkfifo()` or `mknod()`, and two separate processes can access the pipe by name — one process can open it as a reader, and the other as a writer.

For example, one can create a pipe and set up gzip to compress things piped to it:

```
 mkfifo my_pipe
 gzip -9 -c < my_pipe > out.gz &
```

In a separate process shell, independently, one could send the data to be compressed:

```
cat file > my_pipe
```

The named pipe can be deleted just like any file:

```
rm my_pipe
```

---

Another answer would be for the writer to use a named file (perhaps in `/tmp`) to write input data for the child process.  Or, you could have the parent & child processes communicate over a socket, perhaps sending serialized EDN data back & forth.